# How do I update the value inside of a custom component in Wix?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, velo

I have a custom element that I'm using to get color input values in Wix. Currently, I have trouble getting a value from outside of the custom element to show in the custom element. For example, I want to make it so that when a user clicks on a button on my page, the custom element input value is updated. I've tried consulting the [wix manual](https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-editor-adding-a-custom-element-to-your-site#set-the-custom-elements-attributes) for custom elements, but nothing seems to get the value updated.

```
//basic-input.js

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <label for="ucolor">User Color Choice:</label>
  <input type="text" id="ucolor" name="ucolor" value = "802140"><br><br>

</body>
</html>
`;

class BasicInput extends HTMLElement {
  
  connectedCallback() {
    
    this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  
    
  }
  

  
}

window.customElements.define('basic-input', BasicInput);
```

Button Code

```
export function button124_click(event) {
    console.log($w("#basicInputCustomElement").setAttribute("input","value"))
}
```

And the Custom Element settings in Wix:
[Custom Element Attribute settings in Wix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIj1y.png)

Comment: I don't think a custom element can contain that HTML from your template.

Comment: @connexo It displays a user input when I enter the code in the velo custom element. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the info from outside of the custom element into the input. I'm trying to get it to change the value attribute of the html

Comment: You cannot have an element with that template.

Comment: @connexo Does that mean that external data can't be loaded into a custom element? And do you have any examples of HTML that can be used in a custom element?

Comment: Your template is a whole document, not just an element. Remove the DOCTYPE, `<html>` and `<body>` element. Also your element doesn't seem to have an attribute listener for an `input` attribute.

Comment: @connexo I've removed the DOCTYPE, <html> and <body>. Do you have an example of an attribute listener for the input value that would work with Wix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71988295/how-do-i-set-properties-according-to-custom-html-attributes-in-css/71988487#71988487