# How do I set properties according to custom HTML attributes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-component, custom-element

I'm working on Fractions.

My checkpoint is :

```
         
         frac {
             display: inline-block;
             position: relative;
             vertical-align: middle;
             letter-spacing: 0.001em;
             text-align: center;
             
         }
         
         frac {
             display: block;
             padding: 0.01em;
         }
         
         frac {
             border-top: thin solid black;
         }
```

It is working but I want to two things :

- I want to set default values, i.e. `0` to `num` and `1` to `den`.
- I want to do use this type of code to make things simple : 
   `<frac num="0" den="1">` 
  Note :

  - It should not have a closing tag.
  - The `num` and `den` attributes should have their default values if not mentioned.

Btw, I only know CSS.

Comment: There is no `<frac>` element in HTML.

Comment: You can't just create your own HTML elements, only set custom ID, custom classes, or data attributes i.e. `data-frac` or `data-num="0"`

Comment: You can create your own elements. It just needs to be registered via JS, though even if you do not register it, it will work normally on most browsers. Not suggesting this, rather correcting the fact.

Comment: @ZachJensz you can create your own elements as webdev has pointed out, there are rules on naming though (e.g. need a -) and they have to have a closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `<frac>` element in HTML.

To create your own `<frac-el num="3" den="4"></frac-el>`, you can create a small web component, which must adhere to custom element naming rules (name must contain a `-`). It also **will need a closing tag**.

That being said, here we go:

```js
class FractionElement extends HTMLElement {
  numerator = document.createElement('sup');
  denominator = document.createElement('sub');
  style = document.createElement('style');
  
  constructor(n = 0, d = 1) {
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    this.num = n;
    this.den = d;
    this.style.textContent = `
      :host { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; text-align: center; }
      sup { border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
    `;
    this.shadowRoot.append(this.numerator, this.denominator, this.style);
  }
  
  get num() { return this.numerator.textContent; }
  set num(val) { this.numerator.textContent = val; }
  
  get den() { return this.denominator.textContent; }
  set den(val) { this.denominator.textContent = val; }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['num', 'den'];
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal === newVal) return; // nothing to do, no change
    switch (attr) {
      case 'num': this.num = newVal ?? 0; break;
      case 'den': this.den = newVal ?? 1; break;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('frac-el', FractionElement);
```

```html
<frac-el num="3" den="4"></frac-el>
<frac-el num="11" den="27691"></frac-el>
<frac-el></frac-el>
<frac-el num="3x + 7" den="y"></frac-el>
```

Comment: That's a lovely little demo of how to create a custom element (something which I've not really had the time to explore all that much) :)

Comment: @DavidThomas There's no going back once you've started using them.